# Background music for a modern thriller table

Tags: music

First, sorry for my syntax, I'm french speaker and usually only use english for technical topics, but will try to do my best !

I have some friends who asked me to prepare a table as they want to get a first touch with RPG. As they are absolutely not in the medfan world and don't have any experience with any RPG I decided to prepare a low rules table so they can focus on roleplay, happening in "our" city so they already know the place and the possibilities and with a thriller scenario cause they, at least, already have watched a thriller on TV so they could figure out some basic action to do. I think that could be really fun for both of us and not too abstract for them.

But I've barely never organized that kind of setup : modern thriller. (the closer experience was a modern thriller in In Nomine Satanis/Magna Veritas with a band of ol' crazy deamons... so in fact no so close)

The problem is, I'm looking in my music library for some background voice less music and I've barely found nothing excepted the "Vampire The Masquerade: Bloodlines" OSTs and the some tracks from the Matrix ones. The main issue I have is that most of the time they are orchestral (don't fit with what I plan), too futuristic or too voicy...

Do you guys know some similar soundtracks ? I really don't have time to listen to too much OST as I'll be really busy at work this week, I'm actually looking for somes but can't find really relevant stuffs...

Thank's in advance for the big help, I don't want to fail at their first party ! :)

Comment: This may not be the right site for this question, as it doesn't need much knowledge of rpg's to answer.

Comment: Well I thought it was as there's certainly a lot of GM here and somes have certainly already organized those kind of scenarios ? So not "knowledge" but require experience, don't you think ? :/

Comment: A lot of us here could answer (my group almost always has background music playing), but I'm just saying that this question isn't really on-topic here since it doesn't require any knowledge of table top rpg's to answer it.

Comment: Off-topic is not the problem here. This question is an opinion-based question asking for lists of actual tracks with no upper limit. Please take a look at [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/9132/4398); because it asks for procedures and sources instead specific recommendations, it's not opinion-based, nor is it an open-ended list question. If that question's answers don't help you, it shouldn't be too hard to modify your post based on it so that you ask for procedure/source answers. I'm voting to close as too broad because the possible track suggestions are limitless.

Comment: Concurred. The problem is more that it's not possible for us to simply answer the question. For instance, I could say "Well, I like [this](http://open.spotify.com/album/04qhw0DQ7nDR7vmtlU08Fw).", but it's not necessarily a correct answer, nor is there a finite amount of appropriate or inappropriate answers. It's an unsolvable dilemma.