# Music that other people play during a Campaign

Tags: group-dynamics, music

I usually play some random hits station while we play, but I'd like to play something that more envelops what we do in 5e. My party seems to play better when the music matches the mood.

Instead of, you know, like Taylor Swift's "love story" coming on while trying to have the BBEG come out and seem ominous...

What are some songs or soundtracks that other DMs or players have going during their campaigns?

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9132/how-do-i-select-background-music-for-my-rpg-campaign?rq=1

Comment: thank you for not downvoting!! i'll delete this asap. i wasnt sure if it would be sonsidered somethingdifferent

Comment: DON'T delete! Duplicates help finding the answered question.