# What can I use for sci-fi ambient music?

Tags: dark-heresy-1e, shadowrun, music

Another DM I know recently taught me to use ambient music, especially during combat, to keep players more focused on the game and for general atmosphere.  That's all fine and simple for fantasy, plenty of sources.  But I'm at a loss for my Shadowrun and Dark Heresy games.  I know I need the electronic sounds, but Dark Heresy, being 40K, also has heavy Gothic undertones.  Maybe monastic choirs?  Any ideas?

Comment: This is going to be problematic to answer, since it depends significantly on the tastes of you and your players. It would help refine the question if you pointed to specific genre(s) of music you were looking for, as that would give at least a broad sense of what you and your players like.

Comment: There is actually a music subgenre called "ambient" (in the electronica genre) that might suit. Really, any electronica might suit, depending only on your tastes.

Comment: There's practically an immense selection of music out there to choose from, and it really all depends on your taste, so though interesting, I'm afraid this isn't the best question for this site. It's just too subjective. To lend a hand, though, personally I'd suggest giving a listen to the [Dredd OST](http://www.amazon.com/Dredd-Original-Film-Soundtrack/dp/B009AKJ97Q) (The Judge Dredd comics were a huge inspiration for WH40K, and it shows, and the movie's world has a Shadowrun vibe as well, imo.) Alternatively, google & check out the works of Lustmord, an industrial / dark ambient artist.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the [help](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site. I'm afraid this question is probably hard to answer as part of the site proper, but  once you have 20+ rep, feel free to [join the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)! We'll be happy to talk about it there, where the site's Q&A standards aren't an issue.

Comment: PS: For Shadowrun, you might also want to consider buying the Digital Deluxe Edition of the relatively recently published PC/Mac game [Shadowrun Returns](http://store.steampowered.com/app/234650/) which includes the game's soundtrack. :)

Comment: Actually, I created a bunch of Spotify playlists for Shadowrun. [This is the all list.](http://open.spotify.com/user/1210307179/playlist/1yk7AC6XvUYspDPEQoFM1u) There are playlists for [Astral](http://open.spotify.com/user/1210307179/playlist/3gEfJCXmZ55tbIo8TWGXNH), [Sprawl](http://open.spotify.com/user/1210307179/playlist/0FDHYYRKNwjI8SyfuWRa5X), and the [Matrix](http://open.spotify.com/user/1210307179/playlist/7odEjHBiK2yp3VAZ33ipUN) and many others.

Comment: Take a look at this as well: [Shadowrun Online music survey](http://www.shadowrun.com/shadowrun-online/2013/07/09/shadowrun-online-music-survey/) (Official, apparently.)

Answer (score 4):

Film scores can be great background or ambience music for role-playing sessions, for the same reasons that they work well in the film, and there are plenty of films with styles and settings that match those games - they don't even have to be good films, as you're interested in the soundtrack rather than the plot! Some film scores that come to mind are Bladerunner, The Matrix and Johnny Mnemonic.

I would recommend an orchestral or instrumental score rather than a soundtrack that is just a set of songs - look for "OST" or "Original Motion Picture Score" in the title to distinguish, such as in the case of The Matrix which has two soundtrack albums (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix:_Music_from_the_Motion_Picture). You might even make notes while watching a film to help you find the audio track from the score that was played during a fight or a chase.

And it looks like this other question has some good discussion already: [Music during game or not?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/484/music-during-game-or-not)